# How can I edit this SQL code to filter data in table?

Tags: sql, filter, average, aggregate-functions

Suppose we have the following table (called `numbers`):

```
user a b c 
-----------
Jon  0 1 3
Bill 1 2 3
Jess 2 4 2
Jon  1 3 4
```

Executing the following almost performs the calculation I want:

```
CREATE VIEW v_numbers 
AS 
    SELECT  
        n.*, (b / c) - AVG(b / c) OVER (PARTITION BY user) AS e 
    FROM numbers n
```

However, I want to edit this code to exclude rows where column `a` values = 0. Hence, I tried to edit it as follows to filter the data but the code does not work. Does anyone know how it can be amended? I.e. this might be a syntax error.

```
CREATE VIEW v_numbers 
AS 
     SELECT n.* 
     WHERE E a != 0, (b / c) - avg(b / c) OVER (PARTITION BY user) AS e 
     FROM numbers n
```

Comment: There is an arbitrary order of SQL `select` query parts, which are: `select ... from ... [join ...] [where ...] [group by ...] [having ...] [order by ...]`. You cannot put each of it in the place you want. So, please, check the documentation of your database for correct syntax and try to rewrite your query. Also please add your DBMS tag.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to edit this code to exclude rows where column a values = 0

Just use a `WHERE` clause? It goes after the `FROM` clause:

```
CREATE VIEW v_numbers AS 
SELECT n.*, (b / c) - avg(b / c) OVER (PARTITION BY user) AS e 
FROM numbers n
WHERE a <> 0
```

If you want to put a `null` value in column `e` for rows where `a` is `0`:

```
CREATE VIEW v_numbers AS 
SELECT n.*, 
    CASE WHEN a <> 0 
        THEN (b / c) - avg(b / c) OVER (PARTITION BY user)
    END AS e 
FROM numbers n
```

If you want to exclude these rows from the average computation:

```
CREATE VIEW v_numbers AS 
SELECT n.*, 
    CASE WHEN a <> 0 
        THEN (b / c) - avg(CASE WHEN a <> 0 THEN b / c END) OVER (PARTITION BY user) 
    END AS e 
FROM numbers n
```

Some databases (such as Postgres or SQLite) support the standard `filter` clause, so you can do:

```
CREATE VIEW v_numbers AS 
SELECT n.*, 
    CASE WHEN a <> 0 
        THEN (b / c) - avg(b / c) FILTER(WHERE a <> 0) OVER (PARTITION BY user)
    END AS e 
FROM numbers n
```

Comment: I want to exclude them from the calculation which means this solution doesn't quite help

Comment: @HelpNeeded4: I edited my answer with more options.